# Is someone trying to hack my server?

Tags: server, ssh, apache2, webserver, hacking

So I typed `journalctl` after ssh(ing) into the server and got the following output: (so is someone trying to hack system or is it from my side?) 
(Also note the timing says 5am? but most likely none of us login into system at that time? so it something from apache/ubuntu?)

```
Apr 30 05:38:59 bosc-chat sshd[13590]: Failed password for root from 218.92.0.133 port 52094 ssh2
Apr 30 05:38:56 bosc-chat sshd[13592]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=58.242.82.12  user=root
Apr 30 05:38:55 bosc-chat sshd[13590]: Failed password for root from 218.92.0.133 port 52094 ssh2
Apr 30 05:38:54 bosc-chat sshd[13590]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=218.92.0.133  user=root
Apr 30 05:38:53 bosc-chat sshd[13566]: PAM service(sshd) ignoring max retries; 6 > 3
Apr 30 05:38:53 bosc-chat sshd[13566]: PAM 5 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=58.242.82.12  user=root
Apr 30 05:38:53 bosc-chat sshd[13566]: Disconnecting authenticating user root 58.242.82.12 port 58191: Too many authentication failures [preauth]
Apr 30 05:38:53 bosc-chat sshd[13566]: error: maximum authentication attempts exceeded for root from 58.242.82.12 port 58191 ssh2 [preauth]
Apr 30 05:38:53 bosc-chat sshd[13566]: Failed password for root from 58.242.82.12 port 58191 ssh2
Apr 30 05:38:50 bosc-chat sshd[13558]: PAM service(sshd) ignoring max retries; 6 > 3
Apr 30 05:38:50 bosc-chat sshd[13558]: PAM 5 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=218.92.0.133  user=root
Apr 30 05:38:50 bosc-chat sshd[13558]: Disconnecting authenticating user root 218.92.0.133 port 24314: Too many authentication failures [preauth]
Apr 30 05:38:50 bosc-chat sshd[13558]: error: maximum authentication attempts exceeded for root from 218.92.0.133 port 24314 ssh2 [preauth]
Apr 30 05:38:50 bosc-chat sshd[13558]: Failed password for root from 218.92.0.133 port 24314 ssh2
Apr 30 05:38:50 bosc-chat sshd[13566]: Failed password for root from 58.242.82.12 port 58191 ssh2
Apr 30 05:38:47 bosc-chat sshd[13558]: Failed password for root from 218.92.0.133 port 24314 ssh2
Apr 30 05:38:47 bosc-chat sshd[13566]: Failed password for root from 58.242.82.12 port 58191 ssh2
Apr 30 05:38:45 bosc-chat sshd[13566]: Failed password for root from 58.242.82.12 port 58191 ssh2
Apr 30 05:38:44 bosc-chat sshd[13558]: Failed password for root from 218.92.0.133 port 24314 ssh2
Apr 30 05:38:42 bosc-chat sshd[13560]: PAM 2 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=218.92.0.207  user=root
Apr 30 05:38:42 bosc-chat sshd[13560]: Disconnected from authenticating user root 218.92.0.207 port 40772 [preauth]
Apr 30 05:38:42 bosc-chat sshd[13560]: Received disconnect from 218.92.0.207 port 40772:11:  [preauth]
Apr 30 05:38:42 bosc-chat sshd[13566]: Failed password for root from 58.242.82.12 port 58191 ssh2
Apr 30 05:38:42 bosc-chat sshd[13560]: Failed password for root from 218.92.0.207 port 40772 ssh2
Apr 30 05:38:41 bosc-chat sshd[13558]: Failed password for root from 218.92.0.133 port 24314 ssh2
Apr 30 05:38:40 bosc-chat sshd[13560]: Failed password for root from 218.92.0.207 port 40772 ssh2
Apr 30 05:38:40 bosc-chat sshd[13566]: Failed password for root from 58.242.82.12 port 58191 ssh2
Apr 30 05:38:38 bosc-chat sshd[13560]: Failed password for root from 218.92.0.207 port 40772 ssh2
Apr 30 05:38:38 bosc-chat sshd[13566]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost
```

If someone is really trying to hack then is there something i can do about it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Most important, make sure root can't login. `grep Root /etc/ssh/ssdh_config`, there should be something like 'PermitRootLogin no' ... Than think about switching from password authentication to key auth. A look at `Fail2Ban` could not be a bad idea ... And mort important: Do you really need a open SSH on a server in the internet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, someone is actively trying to guess your root password.

Some steps you can do to mitigate the possibility of you getting hacked:

- Make sure your root password is long and unique.
- Check that all your server's aplications and services are updated to
  the current version, and are regularly updated.
- Install an intrusion prevention system. **Fail2Ban** is a very good one
  that will block IP attempts after X number of failed login attempts.
- Reduce the number of IPs that are able to connect to your SSH server
  on your firewall, to your country/region and if possible, ISP. For
  example, if you live    in US, you aren't going to login to your
  server from Rusia or China.
- Hide your server IP behind a proxy service. **Cloudflare** is a great
  provider for that, and has free plans available.
- Establish an email alert to notify you when someone logs in to the server.

I'm sure there are other things you can do to harden your server, but this will be a good start.